# Count() outputs list and not a dictionary in django

Tags: django, django-views

I don't know what's happening this might be easy but I am stuck. I have the below queryset

```
job_title = Employee.objects.filter().values('role__name').annotate(total=Count('id'))
```

output I get `[{'tole__name': 'Manager', 'total':2}, {'role__name': 'Director': 3}]`

now when I try to get the dictionary like `{2, 3}` using `totals = job_title['total]` I get an error

Comment: `{2, 3}` is not a dictionary, but a set, but regardless, how will you reconstruct what role name has that many numbers?

Comment: I am counting number of employees grouping by role

Comment: yes, but if you have a list/set/... of `{2, 3}`, then how do you know what role had two employees?

Comment: I get your question. The thing is I want to create data for a bar chart. Where I will have axis as role names and then the bars as the count. Maybe I’m going about this the wrong way